# Расчет контрольной суммы

Tags: c++

Можете объяснить новичку, что такое контрольная сумма и как ее считать?
 Мое задание: реализовать вычисление контрольных сумм для структур, хранимых в оперативной памяти и файле.
 Функция Add() создает односвязный список:

```
void Add(PRICE*& iinfo, PRICE*& ffirst)
{
iinfo = new PRICE;     


cout << "Введите данные:" << endl;

cout << "   Пол директора магазина(1-man, 2-female): "; cin >> iinfo->Gender;
if (iinfo->Gender == 49)
{
    cout << endl<< " Фамилия директора-мужчины: "; cin >> iinfo->Dir.Fman;
}
else if (iinfo->Gender == 50)
{
    cout <<endl<< " Фамилия директора-женщины: "; cin >> iinfo->Dir.Ffemale;
}
cout << " Название магазина: "; cin >> iinfo->Store;
cout << " Название товара: "; cin >> iinfo->Product;
cout << " Стоимость товара: "; cin >> iinfo->Cost;

iinfo->next = ffirst; 
ffirst = iinfo;
}
```

Функция Record() записывает список в файл:

```
void Record(PRICE*& iinfo)
{
if (iinfo)
{
    ofstream File("Data.txt", ios::app);
    File.write((char*)&iinfo, sizeof(PRICE));

    File.close();

    Record(iinfo->next);
}
}
```

Comment: Какой именно контрольной суммы? Например, можно просто для ваших строк просуммировать значения символов, прибавит значения цифр из чисел - и это тоже будет контрольная сумма... Можно посчитать какую-нибудь CRC16 или CRC32... Конкретизируйте задание. Вам же задание дали не просто так - что-то же на лекциях вам рассказывали?...

Comment: Вот именно, что на лекциях про это не было ни слова. Вот ваш первый вариант мне сгодится. Тогда вопрос, как посчитать значения каждого символа?

Comment: Да сам символ и есть своим собственным значением :) - просто суммируете все `s[i]`...

Comment: А вот, допустим, у меня есть массив структуры. Два поля имеют тип данных char[20]. Могу ли я поле преобразовать к типу (int) таким способом:  int sum=(int)info[i].Store? info - структурная переменная, char Store[20] - одно из полей этой структуры.

Comment: Можно int в принципе и не писать: повышение будет выполнено неявно: `sum += info[i];` преобразует `info[i]` в `int`. Только не суммируйте все 20 символов - после нормальной строки там может валяться мусор...

Comment: struct PRICE  
{
 char Store[20];
 char Production[20];
 double Cost;
};  Это моя структура. Если я напишу: sum +=(int)info[i].Store; sum +=(int)info[i].Production; sum+=(int)info[i].Cost; Можно ли суммировать так все поля структуры?

Comment: Или как мне узнать размер каждого символа элемента массива структуры? Например, как посимвольно узнать размер info[i].Store ?

Comment: Уже разобрался самостоятельно, я просто поле сhar явно преобразовал к string и уже работал со строкой :) Спасибо Вам большое!